# What options are available for upgrading an existing TokuMX database to MongoDB 3.0?

Tags: mongodb, percona, tokumx

TokuMX is a drop-in replacement for MongoDB 2.4 but we're developing some features for our app that really require some of the aggregation features introduced in MongoDB 2.6 and 3.0.

We have a fairly large (>50GB uncompressed) database in TokuMX format, so it would be nice to not have to export the data and re-import. We're not using sharding or replicas.

These are the options I'm aware of:

1. Upgrade to MongoDB 3.0 and install the TokuMXse storage engine (not yet GA)
2. Upgrade to MongoDB 3.0 and use WiredTiger or RocksDB (consequences?)
3. Try out the new Percona Server for MongoDB (https://www.percona.com/software/mongo-database/percona-server-for-mongodb) which looks like it could be a replacement for TokuMX, but it's hard to tell from the marketing.

Answer (score 0):

Percona Server for MongoDB would require you to shut down your cluster and use MongoDump/Restore to move your data from TokuMX to MSMDB. That is exactly why we are staying with the TokuMX release.

Remember that support for ACID transactions and MVCC is not available in MSMDB.

Comment: There is a 0-downtime migration from TokuMX to Percona Server for MongoDB 3.0 documented [here](https://github.com/dbpercona/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration/blob/master/ZeroDowntimeMigration.md)